# what is the shell command to get directory name using filename?

Tags: shell, unix, solaris

In some code i found command like follows :

```
ls | grep Directory 1.txt
```

but above is not working for me 
can any one suggest proper command?

Comment: Do you mean you want the name of the current directory? Or the names of all directories *in* the current directory? Or all names with "Directory" in them? Or the name of the directory containing `1.txt`? Or something else?

Comment: i want the directory name containing 1.txt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command you are looking for is `find`. It will traverse an arbitrarily complex directory structure and report back all files which match the criteria you specify.

```
find . -name 1.txt -exec dirname {} \;
```

This runs the `dirname` command on each matching file, which prints just the directory name.

If you only want to go one directory deep, GNU `find` has a `-maxdepth` option, or you can just use the shell's wildcard matching facilities.

```
dirname */1.txt
```

This assumes the file exists directly in a subdirectory of the current directory, and will only work if there is exactly one wildcard match (`dirname` only works on one file at a time) and the various workarounds are not a lot more elegant than just using `find`.

If, on the other hand, you know that `1.txt` exists in the current directory, the command `pwd` will print out the directory name.

The command `grep Directory 1.txt` will open the file `1.txt` in the current directory, and print out any lines matching the text `Directory`. It will simply ignore the standard input you are feeding it from the `ls` command, which is just as well, because `ls` does not print "Directory" anywhere useful. Also, [parsing `ls` output](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) is very complex, so you should probably avoid trying.

Comment: thx a lot , i found  dirname */1.txt usable

Answer (score 0):

From the [Ubuntu forums](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=739078), you could use

```
dirname `find . -name someFile.txt`
```

Alternatively,

```
dirname /some/path/to/a/file.txt
```

Or you could strip off the last bit of the path grep returns

```
$ F='~/Documents/file.txt'
$ echo $(dirname "$F")
~/Documents
$ echo ${F%/*}
~/Documents
```

Answer (score 0):

Given (just) an arbitrary relative pathname like `1.txt`, it is **impossible** to get the directory name.

Why?  Because there could be lots of `1.txt` files in different directories!  And (presumably) you'd have no way of knowing which was the right one.

If you have a way to disambiguate potential multiple answers, then you *could* use the `find` command to search for the file, and the apply `dirname` to the resulting pathname.  Refer to the respective manual entries, etcetera.  (But beware that `find` will typically search lots of directories, and that is liable to be *expensive".)

If you know that `1.txt` is in the "current directory", then what you are actually asking for is the pathname of the current directory.  You can get that using the `pwd` command.